# csrf-key not as hidden input or as get: How can it be generated?

Tags: python, html, authentication

I try to establish a website-connection(web-login) via python. The login appears to need 3 keys (next to password and username of course). 2 of them are handed over via get and the third one is a csrf-key. The csrf-key is not contained in the html body of the current page nor is it in the link. (I checked this explicitly by using strg+f)

What other common ways are there to generate the csrf-key on the fly? (I explicitly checked by inspecting the post request that the csrf is included in the request, but I don't understand how it gets there)

Answer (score 0):

The csrf key must be somewhere in the webpage you are trying to access.
The csrf key is not generated by the user, instead, it is a unique secret value generated by the server-side application and transmitted to the client.

Comment: I thought the same, but strg+f on the source didn't help me. The only rational conclusion therefore should be, that it is returned by a referenced part right? Like a script that is in a different but included file and therefore not searched through by my strg+f.